# php variable to ajax function

Tags: php, ajax

hi im trying to access a php variable in an ajax function but apparently it isnt working...i have used an onClick event to activate the ajax function where i pass my local php variable as an argument parameter...

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];

?>

<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(x){
var nm = x;
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "my_parse_file.php";
var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;


 var vars = "todo="+fn+"&name="+nm;
hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$display =' Name of list:;   
 echo <label for="name"></label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 </p>
<p>Name of item:
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" /> 
 <br /><br />

 <input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="javascript:ajax_post('   . $name . ');">
</p>
<p>Your list has been succesfully created.</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" name="AddItem" id="AddItem" value="Add Items">
</form>
<p><br />
 <br />
</p>
<div id="status"></div>

</body>
</html>';
?>
<?php
 echo $display;
 ?>
```

Comment: Your question is? What is the error?

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time this question came up, I could melt them all down and build Voltron. PHP is server-side, Javascript is client-side. They don't share variables. The only way to get a PHP variable into a Javascript variable is to explicitly put it there: `var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';` The only way to get a Javascript variable into a PHP variable is to send it to the server via a GET or POST request.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ - Thanks i had tried ur method before but my syntax was wrong...

Comment: @higfox: Also, please edit the question to include an actual *question* rather than a statement and a code snippet. Include any relevant errors or an explanation of actual vs expected behavior. Help us help you.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ- thanks i had forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

Echo the var into a hidden span or input an snag it from there when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're sending the request via POST and then trying to access it via GET.  Try changing it to:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
?>
```